# File upload using jquery not working

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to make a really simple file upload using jQuery, without having to download 3rd party plugin / scripts.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST" name="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    <?php _e('Choose a file to upload') ?>: <input name="uploadedfile" class="uploadedFile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" class="button uploadImage" value="<?php _e('Upload File') ?>" />
  </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php');

  $uploaddir = WP_CONTENT_URL.'/uploads'.$_POST['current_path'];
  $uploaddir = str_replace('/','\\', $uploaddir);
  $uploadfile = $uploaddir .'\\'. basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);


  echo $uploadfile;
?>
```

JS

```
  //File upload
  jQuery('.uploadImage').live('click',function() {

    var current_path = jQuery('#currentPath span').html();
    var new_dir = jQuery(this).find('span').html();

    // Load new content in browser window
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../wp-content/plugins/wp-filebrowser/uploader.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {current_path: current_path, new_dir: new_dir},

        success: function(data){
                 alert(data);
        },

        error: function(){
          alert('Page load failed.');
        }
    });

  });
```

The problem is that I can't get info on `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']`. Is this because the form is never submitted?

Comment: Are you sure the url in your jquery.ajax is correct ?

Comment: At which point are you uploading the actual file?

Comment: Pekka: Exactly ;) That's kind of where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't upload files via ajax. When you do:

```
data: {current_path: current_path, new_dir: new_dir},
```

You're just sending the *location* of the file, not the actual file. The only way to upload a file without a page refresh is to use flash/java/etc, or to submit a form via a hidden iFrame.

I think the jQuery form plugin handles this. [Here's another script](http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html) which will do this.

Comment: This is the root of the problem. The jQuery form plugin uses a hidden iframe to get around it

Comment: Yeah, I tried using IFrame, but couldn't get it to work. Will test with your link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. You're only passing the file path around as request parameter, not the file content as multipart/form data request body. It won't land in `$_FILES`. Also, think once again about it, passing alone the path around ain't ever going to work if the webserver and webbrowser runs at physically different machines.

I'd suggest to have a look at [jQuery Uploadify plugin](http://www.uploadify.com/), it handles all the nasty details of uploading files with Ajax for you transparently.

Comment: I'm using Uploadify in another solution, but I don't want to use flash this time.

Comment: Then go for the jQuery form plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to specify proper settings for:

- file_uploads
- upload_max_filesize
- memory_limit
- max_execution_time
- post_max_size

See:

- [How to optimize your PHP installation to handle large file uploads](http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php)

Also make sure that:

- Specifying the correct path
- Directories have permission, chmod to 755
- Data is coming through, check with:

`print_r($_FILES);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to use a jQuery plugin. Uploadify is good but you'll require:

```
* jQuery v1.2.x or greater
* SWFObject v2.2 or greater
* Flash Player v9.0.24 or greater
```

You can get all the info. on uploadify at www.uploadify.com.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) will help you out with some more options.